# opencsv with intelliJ

Tags: java, csv, jar, intellij-idea, opencsv

I added to my project under `lib` directory the jar of opencsv.
then, in intelliJ under `Project Structure` -> `Libraries` added the jar.

but, somehow intelliJ doesn't recognize it.
why is that?

Comment: What did you try? What do you see in IntelliJ? Did you try to go over some tutorial, like [this one](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Setting_up_a_project_in_IntelliJ_IDEA)?

Comment: Library needs to be added to the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Comment: thanks @CrazyCoder it worked. please write this as answer and I will accept it as the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Libraries** in the **Project Structure** dialog represent the global libraries that can be configured once and then used in multiple projects and modules. To make a library available for a module, add it to the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Answer (score 3):

Don't go this way, create a maven project and it will solve many problems you haven't encountered yet :).

1. Open up you intelliJ Idea
2. select  'File' -> 'New Project' 'Create project from scratch' -> 'Next'
3. Enter the project title, select 'Maven Module' -> 'Next'
4. Click 'Finish' Replace the generated pom.xml with the following:

   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       4.0.0

   ```
   <groupId>opencsvtst</groupId>
   <artifactId>opencsvtst</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
           <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
           <version>2.0</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
5. Under src/main/java add your classes (the one with the main method probably) and use the opencsv library.

You will find the compiled jar within the target folder once you build the project.